# Submit not redirecting

Tags: php, html, css

```
<form method="POST" action="listing.php" class="tg-formtheme tg-formtrip">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="origin" name="options[origin][]" placeholder="ORIGIN">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination" name="options[destination][]" placeholder="DESTINATION">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="options[date][]" id="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="tg-select">
                                            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%">
                                                <option data-tokens="Duration">Duration</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="2 weeks">2 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="3 weeks">3 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="4 weeks">4 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="5 weeks">5 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="6 weeks">6 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="7 weeks">7 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="8 weeks">8 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="9 weeks">9 weeks</option>
                                                <option data-tokens="10 weeks">10 weeks</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Find Tours" class="tg-btn">
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

After clicking on find tours it not redirecting the page which provided in action what i missing can anyone help me. I manually review the code but didn't get any thing Please help how i resolve this?

Comment: is listing.php located in same directory..?

Comment: Working for me, I was redirected to `listings.php`, can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Maybe some javascript or jquery library is preventing form submission

Comment: Is the form submitting but after success it's not redirecting?

Comment: no action perform on submit for me

Comment: What is the name of the file in which the form resides?

Comment: sharing only a portion of your code isn't enough ... am sure if you test **only** this code it wil work for you and for sure you have more code that is creating your issue

Comment: If you don't answer to our questions we can't help you.

Comment: no any action on submit click i m reviewing our full page code

Answer (score 0):

check in the page listing.php that you have the correct redirection first and if you can upload the listing.php code too to check if you have any errors there

Answer (score -2):

There is no mistake in your code,
I check please check attached ss, i print your form data and get the array of values,
Please check it might be issue with your action file. action not getting server side file.
[image]

Put proper route or url to action attribute.